# Fix error no matching function for call to 'assign' in std::vector<std::vector<UC> > lum;

Tags: c++, vector

I have reference code from c++:

```
typedef unsigned char UC;
std::vector<std::vector<UC> > lum;
int h;
int w;
```

And this line code:

```
lum.assign(h,w);
```

I compiled this code and got error: 
no matching member function for call to 'assign'

How can I fix this bug? Is there any matching function with this function which I can replace?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with the call to assign?

Comment: I don't understand it very much. I got it from this source:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tirg/files/

Comment: a 2-D array? You're trying to implement it with vector?

Comment: So, try to understand what you are trying to do, instead of trying to find some syntax that works. No point in having a program do something you don't understand.

Comment: 2-D array? You're trying to implement it with vector? --> –Yes, it looks like this.

Comment: This compiled for me with gcc 4.2.  Is that the complete code (I had to add an #include <vector>?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have a vector of vectors. But you are assigning it like a 1-dimensional vector. What are you trying to achieve? You need to assign a vector to the 2D vector.

Comment: Mine got error: My gcc -v:
gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That error is correct**, as it means that you're trying to assign `h` amount (whatever the value of `h` is) of the value of `w`.

However, as `assign` requires that the value assigned to be an instance the type which is allocated (aka the `value_type`), then you actually need the value to be assigned as of type `vector<UC>`.

In comparison to your code, **you're attempting to assign to the 2-D vector an integer value, which (as stated before), doesn't match the `value_type` of `lum` (`vector<UC>`)** - which explains the error you got. **Why?** Because **a 2-D vector is actually a vector of vectors (of some type).** Hence, **you can only assign a vector of that type to a 2-D vector**, *nothing else*.

In other words, something like this should be the correct code:

```
typedef unsigned char UC;
std::vector<std::vector<UC> > lum;
int h;
int w;

UC initial = 'C';

vector<UC> vec(w, initial);
lum.assign(h, vec);
```

However, as you're trying to populate a 2-D vector, I can only conjecture that you're trying to assign or initialize the vector in some arbitrary way. Depending on what you wish to do, then this approach may not be appropriate.

REFERENCE:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/

Comment: @cat I'm sorry, could you elaborate? I'm afraid I'm not following you.

Comment: @cat Ok cool. If my answer was useful to you, please consider it for acceptance. :)

Answer (score 0):

The overload for `assign` is `void assign( size_type count, const T& value );`, where `T` is `vector<UC>`. The function call of `assign(int, int)` doesn't match.

```
void assign( size_type count, const T& value );

template< class InputIt >
void assign( InputIt first, InputIt last );

void assign( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );
```

The correct call would be something similar to this: `assign(h, vector<UC>(w))`